# iOS Content Blocker app - Subscription Cancelled Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building an iOS Content Blocker app, but running into some diffuculty trying to figure out how to get the content blocker extension to stop working if the user cancels the subscription. Breaking my head over this, would really appricate the help!

Comment: replace your json file with new blank json file, may be it will help

Comment: Pass a Bool Value on click of cancel button and make a check on bool value if value is 1 then extension code will execute if bool value 0 it won't execute